# rename files with changing pattern

Tags: bash, rename

i want to rename different files in bash with pattern and found this option:

```
rename 's/.2007/(2007)/g' *.*
```

with this pattern I can rename every file with ".2007" in name to "(2007)"
--> this is exactly what i want to do.

Next step:
i want to automate this, because i have files with 1995 - 2017. It is a possibility to do:

```
rename 's/.2007/(2007)/g' *.*  
rename 's/.2008/(2008)/g' *.*  
rename 's/.2009/(2009)/g' *.*
```

etc.

but actually, is there another solution?

my files are named like (they are not the same length...):

```
FILENAME.ANOTHERFILENAME.2007.jpg  
FILENAME.2007.jpg  
FILENAME.ANOTHERFILENAME.SOMETIMESONEMORE.2007.jpg
```

Comment: Use for loop and increment the variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Perl‘s rename:

```
 rename -n 's/.([1-2][0-9]{3})/($1)/' *.*
```

This renames all files with 1000 to 2999. If everything looks fine remove `-n`.

Answer (score 0):

For the use-cases where it's not so much about automation but rather about batch processing of a set of files, I find `renameutils` and its `qmv` ("quick move") very useful: it enables you to edit the target filenames in a text editor which may be easier/faster than designing regex's for some.

https://www.nongnu.org/renameutils/ (it's in *buntu repos)

But for applications that need to run w/o human intervention, `rename` is certainly more suitable.